# Descending model relationship laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I am running this query in my laravel app,

```
$project = Project::leftJoin('organisation_user', 'organisation_user.organisation_id', '=', 'projects.organisation_id')
                ->where('organisation_user.user_id', '=', ResourceServer::getOwnerId())
                ->whereNotNull('projects.organisation_id')
                ->get();
```

This returns the data that would expect it to, I can then do this load in the pivot data for the organisation the project is related too.

`$project->load('organisations');`

What I am wanting to do from this point is load in the pivot data for organisations is that possible, in my head it seems like I want to descend through relationships.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the join and do it all at once assuming you have your many-to-many relationship set up for `project` and `organization` models.

```
$project = Project::has('organizations')->with(['organizations'=> function($query){
    $query->where('user_id', ResourceServer::getOwnerId());
}])->get();
```

Or, change things up a bit and call nested relationships.

```
$organization = Organization::with('projects.organizations')->where('user_id', ResourceServer::getOwnerId())->first();

return $organization->projects;
```

If you need additional pivot table data included, you can add `withPivot()` to your relationships.

Comment: This looks nearly exactly what I am wanting to do - BUT (sorry) - A project can be owned by an organisation and that organisation can have any number of users. These are stored in a Pivot table called `organisation_user` and I need to query this based on the `organisation_user.user_id` I can not for the live of me figure out how to this.

Comment: I still may be slightly confused what you're trying to do, but I've added to the answer.  Eager loading the nested relationship may do the trick.